# How can I translate text in a predefined google sign-in button?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, text

Quite new to this and couldn't find a clear answer. I've added the predefined button from the top of this page:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button?hl=no

[As you can see the rest of the text is in norwegian, but I can't change the text in the google button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loTf5.png)

Is it possible at all or do I need another button/code?

```css
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my-signin2"></div>
  <script>
    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
      console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 356,
        'height': 54,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```